# Sliding door without background CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to use markup like this

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/image1.jpg"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="/image2.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And do a sliding door effect?  I have some CSS that looks like this:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
li a { 
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:225px;
}
li a img {
    float:left;
}
li a:hover img {
    float:right;
}
```

It works in FireFox but IE7 doesn't seem to understand the float:left / float:right code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these articles on A List Apart and see if they do what you need:

- [Sliding Doors of CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)
- [Sliding Doors of CSS, Part II](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors2/)

They have a lot of other good articles if you can't sleep like me...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the <li> to block?

```
ul li { display: block; }
```

If I recall correctly, IE had issues with lists, unless you explicitly defined the styles.

As an aside: [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) is a term that has a different meaning to what you describe - might even throw some people off =)

Comment: Does what I'm describing have a title?  I'd like to name this post correctly if possible.

Comment: Hi K Prime, I tried this out and it doesn't seem to work in IE.  Thanks for the prompt response though!